# Spring Boot token-based authentication

Tags: spring, security, authentication, token

How can I implement token-based authentication without cookies for my Spring Boot RESTful application (not MVC)? I've searched the web, but not found any good tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Authentication filter and check the token in header there. Load the used based on the token from your user store and set it as the request principle.

Checkout the following for an example

[Authentication Filter Example](https://github.com/FutureProcessing/spring-boot-security-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/futureprocessing/spring/infrastructure/security/AuthenticationFilter.java)